# Problem with Point ToolTip in Microsoft Charts

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-chart-controls

I have a little problem with tool tip in point. When user moves mouse into Point, Tool Tip is appearing. If point under Axes tool tip is not appearing. How to show points under axis?

Tool Tip is appearing
[image]

Tool tip is not appearing
[image]