# Events in a chart win forms for a point which lies on the axis line in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

[image: Chart form where the point which lies on the axis]

In a chart windows form the point the events for the point which lies on the axis line is not functioning . I have added a tool tip and chart mousedown/chart mouseup functions for the points. But when I change move the axis minimum value it seems to function. For other points which do not lie on the axis the tool tip functions work.

Comment: A similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397895/problem-with-point-tooltip-in-microsoft-charts See, if the solution works for you

Comment: Tried this method but it dint work ,Also this method was to only get a tool tip if at axis. I need a solution for mouseup and mousedown events too .This was the reference i used :https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/04c23273-c683-437c-8f6e-db81e93b54c8/tooltip-for-chart-does-not-show-when-datapoints-are-on-the-axes?forum=MSWinWebChart

Comment: Thanks default locale for the link you have shared , i guess i made some more changes and got to rectify it

Comment: Glad to hear that! You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

With the reference of the below links I was able to make changes in the code and that worked . I segregated the cases for on the axis and the remaining other points in the chart.

[Problem with Point ToolTip in Microsoft Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397895/problem-with-point-tooltip-in-microsoft-charts)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/04c23273-c683-437c-8f6e-db81e93b54c8/tooltip-for-chart-does-not-show-when-datapoints-are-on-the-axes?forum=MSWinWebChart

```
Private Sub Chart1_GetToolTipText(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ToolTipEventArgs) Handles Chart1.GetToolTipText

        Select Case e.HitTestResult.ChartElementType
            Case ChartElementType.Axis, ChartElementType.TickMarks
                Dim result As HitTestResult = Chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y, ChartElementType.DataPoint)
                If result.ChartElementType = ChartElementType.DataPoint Then
                    e.Text = result.Series.Points(result.PointIndex).XValue.ToString & " : " & result.Series.Points(result.PointIndex).YValues(0).ToString
                End If
                Exit Select
        End Select
    End Sub
```